# How can I iterate over a boto3 json nested dictionary and obtain the values?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, loops, boto3, python-3.7

I am trying to loop over the json below and print or gather all the VpcEndPointId values.

```
response = {
    "VpcEndpoints": [
        {
            "VpcEndpointId": "vpce-123",
            "VpcEndpointType": "GatewayLoadBalancer",
            "VpcId": "vpc-test",
            "ServiceName": "com.amazonaws.com",
            "State": "available",
            "SubnetIds": [
                "subnet-random"
            ],
            "IpAddressType": "ipv4",
            "RequesterManaged": True,
            "NetworkInterfaceIds": [
                "eni-123"
            ],
            "CreationTimestamp": "2022-10-28T01:23:23.924Z",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "AWSNetworkFirewallManaged",
                    "Value": "true"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "Firewall",
                    "Value": "arn:aws:network-firewall:us-west-2"
                }
            ],
            "OwnerId": "123"
        },
        {
            "VpcEndpointId": "vpce-123",
            "VpcEndpointType": "GatewayLoadBalancer",
            "VpcId": "vpc-<value>",
            "ServiceName": "com.amazonaws.vpce.us-west-2",
            "State": "available",
            "SubnetIds": [
                "subnet-<number>"
            ],
            "IpAddressType": "ipv4",
            "RequesterManaged": True,
            "NetworkInterfaceIds": [
                "eni-<value>"
            ],
            "CreationTimestamp": "2022-10-28T01:23:42.113Z",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "AWSNetworkFirewallManaged",
                    "Value": "True"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "Firewall",
                    "Value": "arn:aws:network-firewall:%l"
                }
            ],
            "OwnerId": "random"
            }
        ]
    }
```

The issue I am having is the dictionary being nested inside a list. I've been able to get pass one issue where I can print the `VpcEndPointId` KEYS in the code below but still trying to figure out how can I print values.

I tried using .values but it appears the type is a string when I try it with the code below

```
for endpoint in response['VpcEndpoints']:
#for vpc_endpoint in endpoint['VpcEndpointId']:
for vpc_endpoint in endpoint:
    if vpc_endpoint == 'VpcEndpointId':
        type(vpc_endpoint)
```

I'm sure there's something I'm missing and there may be a simpler solution so any suggestions should help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print values of `VpcEndpointId`, it is enough to use one loop:

```
for endpoint in response['VpcEndpoints']:
  print(endpoint['VpcEndpointId'])
```

Comment: Correct, but I am trying to print all vpc endpoints. This appears to print the value in the first nested dictionary but not the second

Comment: @Lam2020 In your example you have only two `VpcEndpointId` and the answer prints those two. There are no nested values.