# How can I iterate over nested dictionaries and lists in boto3 to obtain particular values?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, loops, dictionary, boto3

I'm trying to iterate over these values to retrieve the tags to see if any of the tag values matches `AWSNetworkFirewallManaged`.

I'm having problems figuring out a solution to achieve this.

```
response = {
    "VpcEndpoints": [
        {
            "VpcEndpointId": "vpce-123",
            "VpcEndpointType": "GatewayLoadBalancer",
            "VpcId": "vpc-test",
            "ServiceName": "com.amazonaws.com",
            "State": "available",
            "SubnetIds": [
                "subnet-random"
            ],
            "IpAddressType": "ipv4",
            "RequesterManaged": True,
            "NetworkInterfaceIds": [
                "eni-123"
            ],
            "CreationTimestamp": "2022-10-28T01:23:23.924Z",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "AWSNetworkFirewallManaged",
                    "Value": "true"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "Firewall",
                    "Value": "arn:aws:network-firewall:us-west-2"
                }
            ],
            "OwnerId": "123"
        },
        {
            "VpcEndpointId": "vpce-123",
            "VpcEndpointType": "GatewayLoadBalancer",
            "VpcId": "vpc-<value>",
            "ServiceName": "com.amazonaws.vpce.us-west-2",
            "State": "available",
            "SubnetIds": [
                "subnet-<number>"
            ],
            "IpAddressType": "ipv4",
            "RequesterManaged": True,
            "NetworkInterfaceIds": [
                "eni-<value>"
            ],
            "CreationTimestamp": "2022-10-28T01:23:42.113Z",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "AWSNetworkFirewallManaged",
                    "Value": "True"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "Firewall",
                    "Value": "arn:aws:network-firewall:%l"
                }
            ],
            "OwnerId": "random"
            }
        ]
    }
```

So far I have

```
for endpoint in DESCRIBE_VPC_ENDPOINTS['VpcEndpoints']:
    print(endpoint['VpcEndpointId']['Tags']
```

However this needs to be indice, but if it is I do not know if it will still iterate over the rest of the VPC endpoint ids.

Any suggestions or guidance on this?

Comment: I already [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74597295/how-can-i-iterate-over-a-boto3-json-nested-dictionary-and-obtain-the-values) this question correctly. Please do not make duplicate questions.

Comment: This question is not the duplicate of the previous question. This is regarding tags. This is similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use double for loop:

```
for endpoint in response['VpcEndpoints']:
  for tags in endpoint['Tags']:
    if 'AWSNetworkFirewallManaged' in tags.values():
     print(endpoint['VpcEndpointId'], tags)
```